# "Que j'ai créé" ou "que j'ai eu créé"

Tags: indications-de-temps, temps-surcomposés

Je me suis retrouvé indécis devant une phrase que j'étais en train d'écrire. Le sens que je veux lui donner est le suivant :

> "J'ai créé un objet. Maintenant qu'il est créé, je dois le fabriquer"

Voici ma phrase :

> "Une fois que j'ai eu créé l'objet, je n'ai plus eu qu'à le construire"

Dans ce cas de figure, dois-je utiliser "que j'ai eu créé" ou "que j'ai créé" ? Dans quelle situation dois-je préférer l'un à l'autre ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language Maxime B.  Il me semble difficile de te répondre de façon cohérente dans le contexte que tu indiques parce que dans ta première phrase l'objet n'est pas encore fabriqué et dans la deuxième il est déjà créé et construit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ta phrase :

> Une fois que j'ai eu créé l'objet, je n'ai plus eu qu'à le construire.

est correcte mais personnellement je n'emploierais ni *j'ai eu créé* (passé surcomposé très peu utilisé dans le français de France de nos jours, s'emploie surtout à l'oral dans sud de la France), ni *j'ai créé* (passé composé) auquel je préférerais le passé antérieur :

> Une fois que j'eus créé l'objet, je n'ai plus eu qu'à le construire.

On peut d'ailleurs employer aussi le passé simple dans la principale :

> Une fois que j'eus créé l'objet, je n’eus plus qu'à le construire.

Je trouve cette phrase lourde et peu euphonique avec cette répétition du son /y/ dans « eus » et « eu » et c'est pour cette raison que je choisirais d'employer « rester » au lieu de « avoir à » :

> Une fois que j'eus créé l'objet, il ne me resta plus qu'à le construire.

Personnellement je préfère éviter l'emploi de « une fois que.. » et je pense que la phrase peut être allégée en employant « après + inf. » :

> Après avoir créé l'objet je n'ai plus eu qu'à le construire.
>
> Après avoir créé l'objet, il ne me resta plus qu'à le construire.

---

Toutes ces phrases parlent d'un objet déjà construit. Dans l'optique où ton objet n'est pas encore construit (le contexte que tu donnes avant de donner ta phrase) aucune de ces phrases ne conviendrait, ni même celle que tu proposes dans ta question.

Answer (score 0):

Le problème de la deuxième phrase vient de l’ambiguïté du verbe créer qui est trop proche de construire.

Elle pourrait être levée si concevoir était utilisé à la place :

> Une fois l'objet conçu, je n'ai plus eu qu'à le construire.

Ou alors, en conservant créer :

> Une fois le prototype de l'objet créé, je n'ai plus qu'à lancer sa fabrication (à grande échelle).